# Why is it not possible to access other variables from inside the apply function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Why would the following code not affect the `Output` DataFrame? (This example is not interesting in itself - it is a convoluted way of 'copying' a DataFrame.)

```
def getRow(row):
     Output.append(row)

Output = pd.DataFrame()
Input = pd.read_csv('Input.csv')
Input.apply(getRow)
```

Is there a way of obtaining such a functionality that is using the `apply` function so that it affects other variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What happens

`DataFrame.append()` returns a new dataframe. It does not modify `Output` but rather creates a new one every time.

> ```
>    DataFrame.append(self, other, ignore_index=False, verify_integrity=False)
> ```
>
> Append rows of `other` to the end of this frame, returning a new
>   object. Columns not in this frame are added as new columns.

Here:

```
Output.append(row)
```

you create a new dataframe but throw it away immediately.

### You have access - But you shouldn't use it in this way

While this works, I strongly recommend against using `global`:

```
df = DataFrame([1, 2, 3])
df2 = DataFrame()

def get_row(row):
    global df2
    df2 = df2.append(row)

df.apply(get_row)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
```

Take it as demonstration what happens. Don't use it in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just for the sake of completeness, why would you say it's a bad idea to use `global` that way?

Comment: When you use `global`, you are prone to create implicit dependencies between seemingly unrelated pieces code. This can lead to very hard to understand programs. A function that changes the "outside world" can create a lot of problems that can be hard to hunt down.

Comment: Technically speaking, I think the variable is "outside world" in the case of calling a function through `.apply` is because the function is called internally from the pandas library rather from the script itself. Thus, the variable won't be seen if not `global`.