# Pandas apply function using external variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Dataframe:

```
V1 V2    
1  1    
0  0    
0  0    
0  0    
1  0    
1  1    
0  1
```

I need to compare each *V1* and *V2* row value with an variable called *comienzo*, and  to set a third column named *Label* following this function:

```
def labeling(DataFrame):  
    comienzo=0 #flag to indicate event started (1= started, 0= no started)    
    for n in range(len(DataFrame)):
        if ((DataFrame.iloc[n]['V1']==1 & DataFrame.iloc[n]['V2']==1) & comienzo == 0 ) :
            comienzo=1
            DataFrame['Label']='Start'
        elif ((DataFrame.iloc[n]['V1']==0 & DataFrame.iloc[n]['V2']==0) & comienzo == 1 ) :
            comienzo=0
            DataFrame['Label']='End'
     return DataFrame
```

I want to do this pandorable using `Dataframe.apply`. So, I tried this:

```
def labeling(x, comienzo):  
    if ((x['V1']==1 & x['V2']==1) & comienzo == 0 ) :
        comienzo=1
        Label='Start'
    elif ((x['V1']==0 & x['V2']==0) & comienzo == 1 ) :
        comienzo=0
        Label='End'
    return Label

comienzo=0 #I initialize 'comienzo' var to 0
DataFrame['Label']=DataFrame.apply(labmda x: labeling(x,comienzo),axis=1)
```

This work but values are incorrect, I think that `.apply` doesn't take into account variable *comienzo*.

Is it possible make this code pandorable?

I want this output:

```
comienzo=0
V1 V2    
1 1 Start comienzo=1    
0 1 NaN    
0 0 End comienzo=0    
0 0 NaN    
1 0 NaN    
1 1 Start comienzo=1    
1 1 NaN    
0 1 NaN
```

Comment: Have you tried - `.apply(labeling, args=(comienzo,), axis=1` ?

Comment: No, I don´t. I need the _comienzo_ value of each row for the next row

Comment: I down voted because the title doesn't reflect the actual answer which was in answer to the actual question.

Answer (score 6):

You have a series of small mistakes, ranging from improper lambda usage (mispelling lambda), not using apply properly with args (as noted above), and I'm *pretty* sure you meant to use 'and' instead of & in your conditional logic.

Also your input data is 7 rows, whereas your ideal output is 8 rows, which makes trying to help solve the problem by mapping input->output technically impossible.

However, I think this is what you are trying to get at:

```
DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(
        [[1,1],
         [0,1],
         [0,0],
         [0,0],
         [1,0],
         [1,1],
         [0,1]])
DataFrame.columns=['V1','V2']
DataFrame.insert(0, 'comienzo', 0)

def labeling(x):  
    global comienzo
    if ((x['V1']==1 and x['V2']==1) and comienzo == 0 ) :
        comienzo=1
        return('s')
    elif ((x['V1']==0 and x['V2']==0) and comienzo == 1 ) :
        comienzo=0
        return('end')

comienzo=0
DataFrame['Label']=DataFrame.apply(labeling,axis=1)
```

Note that by using a global for comienzo, we are able to preserve its value through apply-iterations.

Although in many cases using globals is bad practice. Further reading here: [Why is it not possible to access other variables from inside the apply function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34666001/why-is-it-not-possible-to-access-other-variables-from-inside-the-apply-function)

Comment: What is the difference between 'and' operator and '&' operator?  Thank you I know to call global variables now. Your answer was 100% Useful for me.

Comment: This is a great explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i

Basically 'and' is usually what you want, and & is for a more sophisticated comparison.

PS: If you liked my answer please accept it so I get credit :)

Comment: I´m newbie here in stack overflow. How can I do to accept your answer? When I click uparrow vote system shows me: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Of course, I liked your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JuanD To accept an answer, you must be the person who asked the question. Then, you click the "Checkmark"  near the vote arrows, which means "This answer solved my problem".